# writing to a file in android, couldn't locate file

Tags: android, file-writing

so i have this code below in my `MainActivity`, after I call this method, it pop up `Toast` "file saved" but i could not locate this file to be sure it saves what i wanted to, anyone?

```
private void saveToFile(String data){
    try {
        outFile = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/batteryLogFile.txt", true);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        out.println(data);
        out.close();
        //output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/batteryLogFile.txt");
        //output.write(data.getBytes());
        //output.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch(java.io.IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: "i could not locate this file to be sure it sve what i wanted to" -- what did you use for this? DDMS' file explorer and the emulator? If you are testing your app on an Android device, and you are examining [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) via your development PC's file explorer, bear in mind that [you need to index the file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html).

Comment: i don't get any error, everything is smooth and easy, i'm running it on my real device SIII mini, and i couln't locate mentioned file neither through windows explorer nor file browser in my smartphone, i know it is not a condition but my device is also rooted, and what do you mean by "you need to index the file" i am beginner in Android programming so any explanation will be usefull, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the file, issue was about that I was debugging this app on my real device and while it was debugging, somehow app hasn't been saving my file. When I disconnect my device from computer and re-run application again, everything was good and file was located on my SD card.